# where to define a rails view table and instead a mysql table is created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-migrations

I am using RoR3.2 and have a bunch of model objects now. One thing I'd like to do is have a mysql view but I'm not sure where you put it.

```
class CreateQv < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up

    execute <<-SQL
      drop view qv
    SQL

    execute <<-SQL2 #abbreviated view 
create VIEW qv AS select locations.name AS val from locations where (locations.is_enabled = 1) union select concat(menu_items.header,' ',menu_items.detail) AS val from menu_items where (menu_items.is_enabled = 1)
    SQL2
  end
end
```

and I update it via

```
rake db:reset
```

But it creates a table and I'm not sure why. Is this the proper way of creating a view? If yes, why is this the table created?

thx

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK that's the right behavior for a view, to create a pseudo table, that gets updated every time you update the associated tables. The question for me is: why create a view for a rails app? the only reason to create a view I'm aware of, is to deny certain users full access to your data. But in a rails app, you control what you show whom and what they can change.

I might be very wrong though as I'm not too familiar with relational databases.

Edit:
You can test whether your view works by creating a new location and looking for it in your view